# Apply increase to previous row, using field from current row

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, row-number

I have a temp table set up like this:

```
Type    Rate    TotalCost
----    ----    ---------
Type1   0.01    3276.00
Type2   0.01    3276.00
Type3   0.01    3276.00
```

However, I need to take the rate of the current row, times it by the previous total, then add it to the current total...to come up with the new total!

```
Type    Rate    TotalCost
----    ----    ---------
Type1   0.01    3276
Type2   0.01    3308.76
Type3   0.01    3341.85
```

So 1% of 3276 is 32.76.

3276 + 32.76 = 3308.76.

1% of 3308 is 33.08.

3308.76 + 33.08 = 3341.85.

And so on.

I tried creating a CTE, like so..

```
;with cte 
as 
(   
select Type, Rate, TotalCost, row_number() over (order by SortOrder asc) as RowNum   
from @Types
) 

select cur.RowNum, cur.Rate, prev.Rate, cur.TotalCost, isnull(prev.TotalCost * cur.Rate, cur.TotalCost) as NewTotal 
from cte cur 
left join cte prev on prev.RowNum = cur.RowNum + 1
```

...but it's not working :(

Can anyone help?

I'm using SQL Server 2005!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found is to write a loop:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Type VARCHAR(10),
    Rate FLOAT,
    TotalCost MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @Temp (Type, Rate, TotalCost)
VALUES ('Type1', 0.01, 3276.00),
       ('Type2', 0.01, 3276.00),
       ('Type3', 0.01, 3276.00)

DECLARE @CurrentId INT, 
        @Total INT,
        @PreviousCalc MONEY

SET @CurrentId = 1
SELECT @Total = MAX(Id) FROM @Temp

WHILE (@CurrentId <= @Total)
BEGIN
    SELECT @PreviousCalc = Rate * TotalCost
    FROM @Temp
    WHERE Id = @CurrentId - 1

    UPDATE @Temp
    SET TotalCost = TotalCost + ISNULL(@PreviousCalc, 0)
    WHERE Id = @CurrentId

    SET @CurrentId = @CurrentId + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example results, it looks like you're summing all previous rows, instead of just the last one.  You can do that without a CTE, like:

```
declare @YourTable table (type varchar(15), rate float, TotalCost money)
insert @YourTable values
    ('Type1',   0.01,    3276.00),
    ('Type2',   0.01,    3276.00),
    ('Type3',   0.01,    3276.00);

select  cur.Type
,       case 
        when sum(prev.rate) is null then 0 
        else sum(prev.rate * prev.TotalCost) 
        end + cur.TotalCost
from    @YourTable cur
left join 
        @YourTable prev
on      prev.type < cur.type 
group by
        cur.type
,       cur.TotalCost
```

One problem is that there's no sort order in your example data.  I'm sorting on type here; I'm hoping there's a better sort order in your real table!

Another problem is that only the `TotalCost` of the first row matters.  For the following rows, the cost is derived from the first rows' cost, and other rows' rate.